# "one or two friends" vs "one friend or two"

Tags: differences

For example: I'll take "one or two friends" to a party. Or I'll take "one friend or two" to a party. Do these both mean the same? If so, which one is more common?

Comment: You skipped the - in my view - much more interesting question, why does one phrase has a plural s while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same! You can also use "a friend or two".

Comment: IMO this is better (more common) than "one friend or two."

Comment: 'One or two friends' and 'A friend or two' are idiomatic, 'One friend or two' is not.